# Where to ask question about getting DNS/MX issues fixed due to Heroku/Zerigo integration

Tags: discussion

I recently migrated a Rails app I had on Heroku to my domain Hosted on Dream Host and it caused issues with my Google Apps mail. I asked Dream Host and their solution didn't seem to work, and when I asked it here I got down-voted, so I was wondering where I could/should ask that. I want to make sure I use this site properly.

Ref: [DNS/MX issues arising when migrating Heroku app to Dream Host hosted domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/353736/dns-mx-issues-arising-when-migrating-heroku-app-to-dream-host-hosted-domain)

Answer (score 3):

You're in the right place. I assume the downvoter saw your disclaimer on the first line and assumed you were a noob without reading the rest of the post. You should try to cut questions down to *just the actual question*. Putting a warning sign up front that you might be clueless is a good way to attract people who downvote for no good reason. =]

Comment: Ah, fair point! Thanks.

Comment: I think Chris's comment on that question is correct: that's a long, complicated question, with a rambling explanation of what DNS records you created and then a list of other records in a non-standard format...

Answer (score 0):

It might have been downvoted because it's a long rambling post that takes far too long to get to the point. While I didn't downvote this particular one that *is* one of the things I do downvote for.